# WPF DataBinding Requires Manual Raise

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, async-await

I have a view that connects to my viewmodel.  Whenever a user changes the selecteditem from the view, I grab additional data to attach to the selected item.  If I do not raise the property itself after updating the selecteditem, the results will not update on the UI.  This obviously isn't the intended implementation but maybe I'm unclear on the how the property gets notified.

Here is the backing property that binds to multiple controls.

```
public Break SelectedData
{
  get { return _selectedData; }
  set
  {
    if (_selectedData!= value && value != null)
    {
      _selectedData= value;
      DeviceName = value.Feeder;
      OnPropertyChanged("SelectedData");                    
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the combobox that binds the interaction trigger to an asynchronous command in the viewmodel:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Feeders}" DisplayMemberPath="OMSName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData, Mode=TwoWay}" >
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
       <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

In the viewmodel, the selectionchangedcommand executes my asynchronous function to add additional data when the selectionchangedcommand is set:

```
SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayAsyncCommand(UpdateSelectedData); --In the constructor of the viewmodel

public async void UpdateSelectedData()
{
  try
  {
    await _breakRepo.GetEventData(SelectedData);

    if (SelectedData.AttachedEvent.IsOpen)
    {
      SelectedData.Attributes= new EventAttributes
      {
        TotalAffected = SelectedData.AttachedEvent.Attributes.TotalAffected,
        TotalRestored = SelectedData.AttachedEvent.Attributes.TotalRestored,
        TotalOut = SelectedData.AttachedEvent.Attributes.TotalOut,
        TotalCritical = SelectedData.AttachedEvent.Attributes.TotalCritical,
        TotalMajor = SelectedData.AttachedEvent.Attributes.TotalMajor
      };

      await _breakRepo.CallEventsAsync(SelectedData);                   
    }
    else
    {
      await _breakRepo.GetBreakByFeederAsync(SelectedData);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    //IF I ADD ONPROPERTYCHANGED("SelectedData") the other fields that bind 
    //to the values will update as expected

    CurrentlySearching = true;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`

Comment: Can you indicate the line in the code where you "raise the property itself"?

Comment: @GregN Your setter is not getting called and thus the event is not raised. In your command you only mutate `SelectedData` you don't replace it. If you leave it implemented like that then yes you'll need to fire the event yourself to update the binding.

Comment: @EdPlunkett the propertychange is in the finally block (just commented it out).

Comment: @JSteward I'm okay with firing the onchanged manually but for some reason I always assumed if a value changed within an observed property (mutated) it would naturally detect it and raise the property.

Comment: @GregN Please don't use novel terminology that leaves people guessing what you're talking about.

Comment: @JohnyL that does not do what I was looking for.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes I should have made it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to you not reassigning `SelectedData`, the control will never know about any changes.

that is why you manually have to raise the event yourself

in case you bind somewhere to eg. `SelectedData.Attributes` then you might not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `SelectedData` correctly.

Comment: It appears I did not tunnel my model (SelectedData) all the way down with my notifypropertychanged and therefore it wasn't notifying back up.  Implemented the model correctly and now it works without manually raising the property.